# Open Up Window on One Computer from Another over Home Network

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, command-line, powershell

I have two Windows 10 computers connected to the same local home network, and they both have each other's credentials stored so that they can access each other. I would like to be able to use one computer to open a command prompt window on another, and then send it a command to run in that window.

When I say this, I mean that I actually want the physical window to open on the other machine; as in, if I were to walk over to it, I would see that the command window opened up on-screen and is running whatever I command I sent it.

How could I do this from a batch or power-shell script?

Comment: windows has built in remote support. that will let you set one system to allow a 2nd to access the 1st at the same time & in the same session. do a search for "win10 remote support" ... or take a look at this link [*grin*] >>> How to Remotely Troubleshoot a Friend’s Windows PC Without Any Extra Software — https://www.howtogeek.com/268808/how-to-use-windows-10s-quick-assist-to-remotely-troubleshoot-a-friends-pc/

Comment: SE, SU, SO all have rules --- [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Windows is designed to prevent this. You may open an invisible program on the other computer but that's it.

The physical user cannot be interrupted remotely.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a Powershell issue/code problem (which is what this site is for) and not some out of the box that PowerShell can do. This is a Windows OS security boundary and you'd have to use 3rdP tools to do this.

What you can do is create a scheduled task (set to run only if the user is logged on) on a remote host to launch an app/script, to run either at user logon or some other time during the day when a user is already logged on.

You can set that task via PowerShell, as long as you have PSRemoting enabled and properly configured and you must already be an admin on that remote host.